# PHP backwards foreach issue

Tags: php

I want to use foreach to loop through the results of the php scandir function and then display the file name and **then** the size but when I use the code:

```
$scan = scandir("/home/foo");
foreach ($scan as $value) {
echo "$value" . "<br>" . filesize("/home/foo/$value") . " ";
}
```

what I end up with is the filesize value first and then the $value, like this:

```
3337 Desktop
4096 Downloads
4096 Mail
4096 Scripts
```

Why is this? and how do I get it to format in the same order as the code, ie. name of file and then the file size?

Comment: If you look at the PHP manual for scandir, you will see that the first and second values of the returned array are usually `.` and `..`, and that may be causing the `<br />` to offset your outputs.

Comment: Don't use a variable in quotes like that:  `"$value"`.  Just use `$value`.

Comment: Thank you @David that explains most of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a line feed (`<br>`) between the value and the filesize, but not after the filesize.

Therefore the filesize will appear as the first thing on a new line, and the name of the next element will appear next to it. So it actually is outputting things in the right order; it just doesn't look that way in the printed output.

Solution:

Swap the `"<br>"` and the `" "` parts of the string.

```
echo "$value" . " " . filesize("/home/foo/$value") . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `<br>` to the end, it is a line break and starts a new line.